# reduction of an admissible filtration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $(R,m)$ be a local ring and $I$ an $m$-primary ideal of $R.$ $\lbrace I_n\rbrace_{n\in\mathbb{Z} }$ is called $I$-admissible filtration

1) if $m\geq n$ then $I_m\subset I_n.$

2) for all $m,n,$ $I_m I_n\subset I_{m+n}.$

3) for all $n,$ $I^n\subset I_n.$

4) for all large $n,$ $I_{n+1}=II_n.$

$J\subset I_1$ is called reduction of $\lbrace I_n\rbrace$ if $JI_n=I_{n+1}$ for all large $n.$

Now suppose $J\subset I$ and $J$ is reduction of $\lbrace I_n\rbrace.$ Can we say that $J$ is reduction of $I$ ?

Comment: Dear user 36611: When you have an answer to your questions, it is good practice to accept it, or to explain why it is unsatisfactory.

Comment: Is $R$ Noetherian? Is $I_n$ an $R$-ideal?

Comment: Yes. R is Noetherian.

Comment: This question is no longer relevant because it has received a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $I_n$ are ideals and $I_0 = R$, then the answer is yes.

Consider the following ring extensions;
$$
R[Jt] \subseteq R[It] \subseteq \oplus I_n. 
$$
Since $J$ is a reduction of $\{ I_n \}$, the extension $R[Jt] \subseteq \oplus I_n$ is module-finite, i.e., $\oplus I_n$ is a finitely generated $R[Jt]$-module. Therefore, it is Noetherian. The module $R[It]$ is a submodule of a Noetherian module. Hence $R[It]$ is a finitely generated module over $R[Jt]$. This show that $J$ is a reduction of $I$.